# how to convert mysql binary(16) key back to hex string

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql insert that is throwing the following error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1: Duplicate entry '\x02L\xA6C\x18 \xAA\xC2K\xBF\xDDX\x97\xFA\xBB6-4.1.3.41' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

The table's primary key is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_vmv_extended` (
  `variant_hash` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `pipeline_version` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  ....
PRIMARY KEY (`variant_hash`,`pipeline_version`)
)
```

I understand the duplicate entry problem, I just can't for the life of me figure out how to turn the BINARY(16) representation in the error message back into our original string of 32 hex digits.

We are using mysql's function unhex('01DA4E4D7EA7D85800FD08A9F09085B1') on the inserts to generate the binary(16) values.

Comment: The inverse of `unhex` is `hex`.

Comment: Do you want MySQL to show a readable representation in error message?

Comment: no it does not have to be 'readable', I just don't understand this representation at all.   How does this represent 16 bytes of anything?

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured this out.   I was confused when breaking up the hex string from mysql because my editor was throwing away the space (' ') after \x18 so I kept coming up with only 15 bytes to convert not 16.  You break up this string as follows where each of the lines represents one byte of information.

```
    orig hex representation:\x02L\xA6C\x18 \xAA\xC2K\xBF\xDDX\x97\xFA\xBB6

    \x02
    L
    \xA6
    C
    \x18
        <- this is a single space
    \xAA
    \xC2
    K
    \xBF
    \xDD
    X
    \x97
    \xFA
    \xBB
    6
```

This gives us 16 bytes.  I don't know how to get mysql to directly convert this back into a hex string, but python can do it like so....

```
python
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> from binascii import hexlify
>>> a='\x02L\xA6C\x18 \xAA\xC2K\xBF\xDDX\x97\xFA\xBB6'
>>> hexlify(a)
'024ca6431820aac24bbfdd5897fabb36'
>>> unhexlify(hexlify(a))
'\x02L\xa6C\x18 \xaa\xc2K\xbf\xddX\x97\xfa\xbb6'
```

A quick test on my data database shows that the conversion is correct as this query finds a record.  I can use the output of the hexlify function above as the input for the filter.

```
select * 
from new_vmv_extended
where variant_hash = unhex('024ca6431820aac24bbfdd5897fabb36')
and pipeline_version = '4.1.3.41'
```

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 2):

I made some analyzing of MySQL logs. So I have some assumptions.

Duplicate entry value is index value and it *does not exact match* original `BINARY(n)` data in row.

Most easiest way for me to find original row in database was the following:

For example MySQL logged index value `'\x08\xD69\x0B\x13\xAB:\x07\xDA\xC5\xDE\xC5a_0\xCD'`.
To create search pattern we should use 2 chars after each hex delimeter (`\x`).
Something like this for above example: `'08%D6%0B%13%AB%07%DA%'`.

Resulting query will look similar to this one:

```sql
SELECT Id
FROM MyTable
WHERE HEX(Id) LIKE '08%D6%0B%13%AB%07%DA%';
```

The query gives me exactly 1 rows as result from my database.

All is tested on **MariaDB 10.4**.